# split PDF file and the new file name is the bookmarks this with sejda

Tags: java, sejda

I need to split a PDF file.

The name of the new file is the Bookmarks (2 level) of the original file.

Now I do that with pdfsam, but I need do it in my server linux with [sejda](http://www.sejda.org/).

I can split the pages and using the same name, but can't name the file with of the bookmark.

how can I do that?

Comment: Please edit this question to add a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you're trying to do, what you expect, and what happens instead.

Comment: I use it:  root@digcr [/home/crlis/sejda-console]# bin/sejda-console splitbybookmarks -f abril01.pdf -p [BOOKMARK_NAME] -o /B/ -l 2 22:31:15.080 Configuring Sejda 1.0.0.M9 22:31:15.093 Loading Sejda configuration form default sejda.xml 22:31:15.271 Starting execution with arguments: 'splitbybookmarks -f abril01.pdf -p A B -o /B/ -l 2' 22:31:15.271 Java version: '1.7.0_55' 22:31:15.335 Option only takes one value: --outputPrefix -p value : prefix for the output files name (optional) root@dipgcr [/home/crlis/sejda-console]#

Comment: as requested, please edit the question to explain that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bin/sejda-console splitbybookmarks -f input.pdf -p [BOOKMARK_NAME] -o /tmp/sejda-output/ -l 2
```

Comment: Hi, tanks for your time, see that root@digcr [/home/crlis/sejda-console]# bin/sejda-console splitbybookmarks -f abril01.pdf -p [BOOKMARK_NAME] -o /B/ -l 2
22:31:15.080 Configuring Sejda 1.0.0.M9
22:31:15.093 Loading Sejda configuration form default sejda.xml
22:31:15.271 Starting execution with arguments: 'splitbybookmarks -f abril01.pdf -p A B -o /B/ -l 2'
22:31:15.271 Java version: '1.7.0_55'
22:31:15.335 Option only takes one value: --outputPrefix -p value : prefix for the output files name (optional)
root@dipgcr [/home/crlis/sejda-console]#